# Swift: Clearing .sharedApplication().shortcutItems on application quit

Tags: swift, 3dtouch

I'm having a very simple problem with my implemented 3D Touch dynamic quick action shortcuts.

I want the shortcuts to be cleared whenever the app is terminated (by double clicking the Home button and swiping up).

I am calling `UIApplication.sharedApplication().shortcutItems.removeAll()` as follows:

```
func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    UIApplication .sharedApplication().shortcutItems?.removeAll()
    self.saveContext()
}
```

However it has no effect, and the quick actions still show when 3D touch is used.

If I place `UIApplication.sharedApplication().shortcutItems?.removeAll()` inside 
    `func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication)`, this works exactly as intended...

I read something about `applicationDidEnterBackground` being the function used in most cases due to background processing or something...but there has to be a way to achieve what I want when the user terminates the app using the app monitor swipe up.

Thanks

Comment: Seems you have a miss-added space after `UIApplication:` `UIApplication<SPACE HERE>.sharedApplication().shortcutItems?.removeAll()`, possibly try removing that.

Comment: Thanks but that had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't tried this. But this tweak should work.
Start a background task on applicationWillTerminate and end it after some small delay. In the mean time, you can call 'UIApplication .sharedApplication().shortcutItems?.removeAll()'.
This will hopefully clear the shortcut items.

Answer (score 0):

There are dynamic and static quick actions. The first kind you define through the shortcutItems property of the UIApplication instance (like in your example). The second kind you register in the plist file.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationshortcutitem):

> Your code creates dynamic quick actions, and registers them with your app object, at runtime.
>
> The system registers your static quick actions when your app is installed.
>
> If a user installs an update for your app but has not yet launched the update, pressing your Home screen icon shows the dynamic quick actions for the previously-installed version.

This means that even when the app is closed the system remembers about both kinds of quick actions. While your app is in memory, such as when going into background, the system can still query the UIApplication for the dynamic actions but it must keep some other sort of persistence of quick actions when the app is closed.

I think there is just no guarantee about the point at which the system synchronizes with the dynamic quick actions. My guess is that the system does not necessarily synchronize when closing the app, yours might be an unsupported use case.